# How do I change the default background color of class .active list-item in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css

Boostrap code :

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="sidebar-heading"><strong><?= __('Admin Panel') ?></strong></div>
<div class="list-group list-group-flush">
<a href="#" id = "dashboard-tab-btn" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action active"><?= __('Dashboard') ?></a>
<a href="#" id = "users-tab-btn" class="tablinks  list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Users') ?></a>
<a href="#" id = "instructors-tab-btn" class="tablinks  list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Instructors') ?></a>
<a href="#" id = "courses-tab-btn" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Courses') ?></a>
<a href="#" id = "enrolled-tab-btn" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Enrolled Students') ?></a>
<a href="#" id = "instruct-courses-tab-btn" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Instructor Courses') ?></a>
<a href="#" id="transactions-tab-btn" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action"><?= __('Transactions') ?></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to override the default bootstrap properties and change the background-color when the list item is active, the below code is not working:

```
.active{
    background-color: #00cccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding !important after the color.

```
.active{
    background-color: #00cccc !important;
}
```